# Count of ascending triplets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I would like to solve a problem where in I am given a set of numbers and I have to find the count of all ascending triplets which can be derived from that set.

For eg:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

the output would be `4`
the solution would be

```
[1,2,3]
[1,3,4]
[2,3,4]
[1,2,4]
```

What can be the possible formula for that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply $$\binom n3,$$
the number of ways to choose subsets of size 3 from $n $ numbers.